# SFTP from Travis CI build fails with host key verification error and connection reset error

Tags: sftp, travis-ci

I am attempting to use `after_success` in a Travis CI build to deploy files to a remote server using SFTP. However, I am getting errors that prevent the upload from succeeding.

SFTP command and resulting error message:

```
$ sftp -b upload_sftp -i upload_key -P 2222 $sftp_user
Host key verification failed.
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

The SFTP batch file `upload_sftp` contains various `put` commands.

Answer (score 1):

As the "Host key verification failed" message hints, you need to add your server's keys to the `known_hosts` file, as documented in [the Travis CI Documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ssh-known-hosts/).

Adding the following to `.travis.yml` uses `ssh-keyscan`:

```
addons:
  ssh_known_hosts: git.example.com
```

Alternately, `known_hosts` can be appended to directly using

```
install:
  - echo 'KEY' >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
```